# Is there a way to run VB.net on vscode

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I’ve tried all the vb extensions and nothing appears to be working. Dotnet works on the terminal and other programs are working but not vb.net. Some say there’s no support but I was wondering if that is the case? Is there any extension that can run and debug vb.net on vscode?

Comment: it can do .NET C#, what is used to compile vb.net, which tool of VS does the VB.NET and is it installed if you install a .NET version

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't currently a VB plugin for VSCode.  I'd recommend using Visual Studio if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try the VS Code Extension [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner).

I had to add the path to `vbc.exe` to the `path` environment variable to make it work.